# need distribute group value based on weightage avg

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

my table data structure like that.

| SNo | Name | Color | Ref no | OrdQty | Act Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ankur | Red | 1.1 | 80 | 120 |
| 2 | Ankur | Red | 1.2 | 30 | 120 |
| 3 | Neeraj | Black | 1.1 | 50 | 110 |
| 4 | Neeraj | Black | 1.2 | 50 | 110 |
| 5 | Neeraj | Red | 1.3 | 30 | 28 |

I need to distribute "ACT Qty" based on weightage avg. weightag avg calc. based on "ordqty" in group by Name , color. with new column weightage.
result as below

| SNo | Name | Color | Ref no | OrdQty | Act Qty | Wightage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ankur | Red | 1.1 | 80 | 120 | 87 |
| 2 | Ankur | Red | 1.2 | 30 | 120 | 33 |
| 3 | Neeraj | Black | 1.1 | 50 | 110 | 55 |
| 4 | Neeraj | Black | 1.2 | 50 | 110 | 55 |
| 5 | Neeraj | Red | 1.3 | 30 | 28 | 28 |

Formula

| S | Name | COl | Ref | ordqty | Actqty | Formula cal | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ankur | Red | 1.1 | 80 | 120 | (80/110)*120 | 87 |
| 2 | Ankur | Red | 1.2 | 30 | 120 | (30/110)*120 | 33 |

```
formulacal= (ordqty/sum(orderqty))*actqty=87 
            (ordqty/sum(orderqty))*actqty=33
```

Comment: Please show the necessary calculation formula

Comment: |1 |Ankur|Red  |1.1 |80 |120    |(ordqty/sum(ordqty))*actqty|(80/110)*120|87      |
|2 |Ankur|Red  |1.2 |30 |120    |(ordqty/sum(ordqty))*actqty|(30/110)*120|33      |

Comment: please edit and update that in your question. It is hard to read in the comment

Comment: The problem is going to be in the rounding. How do you want to handle that?

Comment: round them upper level

also
can we distribute act qty based on ordqty. like if ordqty ankur 80 and 30 but ACTQTY 80 only so its 1st distribute that on 80 ref. 1.1 because its earlier ref. and 1.2 0. or if my actqty is 100 so distribute ankur weightage 80 20. weightage formula work when my actqty going beyond ordqty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function to obtain the `sum(ordqty)` of a group.

```
Wightage = OrdQty * 1.0 
         / sum(OrdQty) over (partition by Name, Color) 
         * ActQty
```

multiplication by `1.0` is to avoid integer division

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RzwZyH1x)

Comment: this sol. distribute actqty equal. i need to distribute based on ortqty wightageavg of actqty.

Comment: Did you try the query? See demo

Comment: **@Squirrel**
can we distribute act qty based on ordqty. like if ordqty ankur 80 and 30 but ACTQTY 80 only so its 1st distribute that on 80 ref. 1.1 because its earlier ref. and 1.2 0.

or if my actqty is 100 so distribute ankur weightage 80 20. weightage formula work when my actqty going beyond ordqty

Comment: This differs from your original question. Please do accept the answer and ask a new question with the new requirement

Comment: help if you provide or update on original

Comment: Ask a new question with the details, sample data and expected result and any calculation, formula involved. You will get more help as a new question.